# How to get a Google sheet ID which doesn’t exist yet?

Tags: python, google-sheets, pivot-table

I have a Google Worksheet with which I'm doing pivot tables.
I would like to add pivot tables(14) in new sheets that don’t exist yet (One pivot table by sheet), on the same spreadsheet.
Currently I'm creating new sheets and recovering their IDs by hand. I wish it was automatic.
Here my pivot table :

```
    request_body = {
        "requests" : [
            {
                "addSheet": {
                    'properties': {
                        'title': 'test',
                        'tabColor' : {
                            'red' : 0.44,
                            'green' : 0.99,
                            'blue' : 0.50
                        },
                    }
                },
            }
        ],
        "sheets":[{
            'data': [{
                "rowData" : {
                    "values" : [
                        {
                            "pivotTable" : {
                                #Data Source
                                "source" : {
                                    "sheetId": "0",
                                    "startRowIndex" : 0,
                                    "startColumnIndex" : 0,
                                },
                                #Row Field(s)
                                "rows" : [ 
                                    #field 2
                                    {
                                        "sourceColumnOffset" : 5, #Type Preneur
                                        "showTotals" : False,
                                        "sortOrder" : "ASCENDING"
                                    },
                                    #field 3
                                    {
                                        "sourceColumnOffset" : 3, #Enseigne
                                        "showTotals" : False,
                                        "sortOrder" : "ASCENDING"
                                    }
                                ],
                                #Columns Field(s)
                                "columns" : [
                                    #Field 1
                                    {
                                        "sourceColumnOffset" : 6, #Nature impayés
                                        "sortOrder" : "ASCENDING", 
                                        "showTotals" : False
                                    },
                                    #Field 2
                                    {
                                        "sourceColumnOffset" : 18, #Année
                                        "sortOrder" : "ASCENDING",
                                        "showTotals" : True
                                    },
                                    #Field 3
                                    {
                                        "sourceColumnOffset" : 19, #Item - Entry Type
                                        "sortOrder" : "ASCENDING",
                                        "showTotals" : False  
                                    }
                                ],
                                "criteria" : {
                                    6:{
                                        'visibleValues' : ['Solde Créditeur']
                                    },
                                    19:{
                                        'visibleValues' : [
                                            'DEPRD', 'DEPRE', 'ECHEA', 'FACTU'
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    5: {
                                        'visibleValues' : [
                                            "Inconnu", "Indépendant","Antenne / Wifi", "SL", "Franchisé", "Ephémère", "Copro", "Carrefour", "-"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                },                                        
                                #Values Field(s)
                                "values" : [
                                    {
                                        "sourceColumnOffset" : 21, #PNS BRUT PPSO
                                        "summarizeFunction" : "SUM",
                                        "name" : ""
                                    }
                                ],
                                "valueLayout" : "HORIZONTAL"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    'dataSourceId' : id_fichier
                },
                'fields' : 'pivotTable'
            }]
        }]
    }

    #Ecriture du 1er TCD
    response = service_sheet.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(
        spreadsheetId = Id_fichier_source,
        body = request_body
    ).execute()
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Hi, if I understand correctly, do you need to create a document using the API? I leave you a link that demonstrates how to do it in [python](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create), you can add the pivot table request, inside of the `spreadsheet_body`.

Comment: Hi @Emel ! Thank you :)  I need to add my pivot table in a new spreadsheet. This **spreadsheet doesn't exist yet**. As the spreadsheet id's is unknown, I don't know what do have I to insert in the target source   : `  "start" : {
                        sheetId : "******", `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily create a new spreadsheet using the [`spreadsheets().create()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/python/latest/sheets_v4.spreadsheets.html#create) method.

An [example](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/create#python):

```
spreadsheet = {'properties': {'title': "Testing-01"}}
spreadsheet = ss_service.spreadsheets().create(body=spreadsheet,
                                            fields='spreadsheetId').execute()
ss_id = spreadsheet.get('spreadsheetId')
print('Spreadsheet ID: {0}'.format(ss_id))
```

After that you simply have to add the generated ID to your function

###### Update

You can add a new sheet to an existing Spreadsheet using the [`addSheets`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addsheetrequest) request. To note, you set its own ID so that it can then be referenced later.

So, the steps will be:

1. Create and take the ID of the Spreadsheets.
2. Create with the `AddSheet` method all the new tabs that are needed. Set an ID for each new sheet added.
3. Set these IDs inside [`updateCells > range > sheetID`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#gridrange).

For reference, you can use these [examples](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet)

###### Documentation:

- [Google Sheets API PyDoc](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/python/latest/index.html)

Comment: Hi @Emel, thanks a lot ! I m sorry, I did a mistake by translating in English my request. I want all my pivot tables on different sheets but on the same spreadsheet. Inside the first sheet there are my data with which I do the pivot tables.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it to see if it meets what you needs.

Comment: Thanks so much @Emel for your help. So I can create a new empty Sheet with your method. But when I want to insert my pivot table with "GridData", I'm getting an 'unknow name rowData" : `"addSheet": { 'properties': {
 'title': 'test', 'rowData' : [{ "values" : [ { "pivotTable" : {
                                         `

Comment: I updated my request - I read the API and example you send me - I think I had a syntax error. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @Larow It's seems that you are trying to modify the sheets within the `addSheet` request, have you tried doing iy inside `updateCells` one? Just store the ID for this new sheets, and use it later in your script.

Comment: I did it @Emel - it works now ! Thank you a lot

Comment: Glad to hear it!